# Debian: record mic (audio in) and speaker (audio out) at same time without heating mic repeat on speaker?

Tags: audio, microphone, audio-recording

Trying to have a setup which records audio in and out at the same time without having to hear the mic repeated on the output device (speaker). There is a procedure which gets this to work on Windows: https://mattdemers.com/recording-two-separate-tracks-podcast-with-voicemeeter/

I tested the above and it does indeed seem to work, but it's a bit clunky and it looks like it is designed for Windows specifically. Is there a way perhaps via command line to have the same sort of setup on a linux machine? ideally with the IN and OUT audio being recorded to separate streams as in the example I posted, and then with a command to quickly revert the settings back to normal when this recording feature is not being used.

Comment: why would you need to record the output?

Comment: is the title correct?

Comment: This is to record an entire Google Voice call: both sides of the conversation.